# Break text in input field after desired point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a jquery dialogue box. In that box, there are text fields. So, in one of the fields, I want the text to appear in next line
after certain value. In various places, I have seen people using \n to make appear text in the second line but I was not able to the same.
This is my HTML of that text field

```
<input id=message class="inputFeild"  style="height:60px type="text">
```

and here is script where test1, test2, test3 are some variables whose values I am getting from somewhere else

```
var message = "Message is :"+test1+" \n "+"\n new line :"+ test2+"\n again new line " +test3

$(this).find('#message').val(message);
```

I have also used it like this

```
var text = $('#message');
$(this).find(text).val(message)
```

as well as

```
$(this).find(text).val("Message is :"+test1+" \n "+"\n new line :"+ test2+"\n again new line " +test3)
```

But when I used the same in console.log I was able to see second line.

How to break text in second line after desired point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *textarea* in place of input 
use *cols* and *rows* attributes for texareas size:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
```